# How to manage NULL to reshape data in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data in a table as shown in the bigger table in the picture.
I would like to reshape it by managing NULL and create small table as shown.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I assume you want to rely on record order to do this - how are you sorting?

Comment: what's the query look like? This looks like a UNION result or something that might do better for you with JOINs, or vice versa, depending on the table structures

Comment: RedFilter, I just need to get rid of NULL. I dont have to worry about the sorting order. Thank you

Comment: How are you connecting ICD9 and ICD10 codes? I work with these a bit from time to time, and I know it's challenging at best to connect them.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that there is a one to one match between rows with a null ICD-9 field and a ICD-10 field and that you want them matched up alphabetically sorted and matched:

```
select A.Ruleid,
    A.Shortdesc,
    A.[ICD-10],
    B.[ICD-9]
from
    (
    select Ruleid, 
        Shortdesc, 
        row_number() over (Partition by Ruleid, Shortdesc order by [[ICD-10]]) rw,
        [ICD-10]
    from TheTable
    where [ICD-9] is null
    ) A
join
    (
    select Ruleid, 
        Shortdesc, 
        row_number() over (Partition by Ruleid, Shortdesc order by [[ICD-10]]) rw,
        [ICD-9]
    from TheTable
    where [ICD-10] is null
    ) B
on A.Ruleid = B.Ruleid
    and A.Shortdesc = B.Shortdesc
    and A.rw = B.rw
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly there is no valid way to do this with your structure. There is nothing to link the records together and know which ones genuinely belong together. Without a business rule, the connections are random and thus suspect.

Also remember that you cannot tell the order in which records were entered in this table structure, so you can't make the assumption that the first record you see for ICD 10 is the one that belongs with the first record you see for for ICD9. And will there ever be a problem of a record that only has one or the other of the two records? How will you handle this?

Yes I could write a query to get the results you asked for, but the results would not be correct by any stretch of the imagination. This task is simply not possible without redesigning your database.

Answer (score -1):

I would do it with a hash in perl. you will need to change the database
access for MSSQL, where in my example below its using my own DB abstraction module for MySQL. but you should get the basic idea.
now your example did not have any different values for Ruleid or Shortdesc,
so if you have different values in your source table you need to revamp this
as it does not take that into consideration

```
 my(%DATA);
 my($count)=0;
 $DB->OpenQuery("SELECT Ruleid,Shortdesc,'ICD-10' FROM SOURCETABLE WHERE 'ICD-9' is NULL ORDER BY <WHATEVER YOU DID>");
 while(my($r,$s,$i) = $DB->FetchRow())
 {
    $count++;
    $DATA{$count}{'Ruleid'}=$r;
    $DATA{$count}{'Shortdesc'}=$s;
    $DATA{$count}{'ICD-10'}=$i;
 }
 $DB->CloseQuery();

 $count=0;
 $DB->OpenQuery("SELECT 'ICD-9' FROM SOURCETABLE WHERE 'ICD-10' IS NULL ORDER BY <WHATEVER YOU DID>");
 while(my($i) = $DB->FetchRow())
 {
    $count++;
    $DATA{$count}{'ICD-9'}=$i;
 }
 $DB->CloseQuery();

 foreach my $k (sort { $a <=> $b } keys(%DATA))
 {
    $DB->Do("INSERT INTO NEWTABLE SET Ruleid=?,Shortdesc=?,'ICD-9'=?,'ICD-10'=?",$DATA{$k}{'Ruleid'},$DATA{$k}{'Shortdesc'},$DATA{$k}{'ICD-9'},$DATA{$k}{'ICD-10'});
 }
```

Comment: When all you have is a hammer everything look like a nail :)